# How to insert a SupportMapFragment in an activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I have created with AndroidStudio the automatic activity for the map.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mitic.mappa.MapsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/contenitore"
    android:background="#ccebff">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3365ff"
        android:id="@+id/navBar">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dove vuoi andare?"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#3365ff"
            android:onClick="scegliPercorso"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mappa generale"
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="visualizzaMappaGenerale"
            android:background="#3365ff" />

        <Button
            android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Informazioni UnisaMapp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="info"
            android:background="#3365ff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/navBar"
        android:id="@+id/layout2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/contFragment">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_below="@id/layout2"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I would like to put this activity in a class in order to call this method startResolutionForResult(getActivity(),REQUEST_LOCATION) (getActivity() I can not call it FragmentActivity).

This is my class MapsActivity

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

        private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
        final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;

        private static final LatLng FISCIANO = new LatLng(40.77502, 14.79018);
        private String providerId = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        private String providerNetwork = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        private LocationManager locationManager = null;
        private static final int MIN_DIST = 10;
        private static final int MIN_PERIOD = 5000;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private Location mCurrentLocation;
        private ListaItinerari itinerari;
        private FragmentManager fm;
        private Polyline polyline;
        private Marker sonoQui, destinazione;
        private ListaMarkers listaMarker;
        private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("MapsActivity", "onCreate");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
            itinerari = new ListaItinerari();
            fm = getFragmentManager();
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("MapsActivity", "ReadyMap");
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(FISCIANO));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Accetta i permessi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I would like to add this fragment in an activity and so i create this class

```
public class Appoggio extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
    }
}
```

This is map_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Appoggio"
    android:background="#ccebff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containers">
    </RelativeLayout

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I add in this layout the MapsActivity class?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

put a view pager in your main activity and then add your fragment to the view pager

```
ViewPager pager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 TabsPagerfragment tabsPagerfragment=new TabsPagerfragment(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
```

Hope this would help you!